# Magento 2.3 programmatically refresh smart rules without saving category

Tags: magento2.3, category, rules

In my magento enterprice I have set a smart rule on a category (let's call it category B) which populates it's products with the product of another category (let' s call it category A). From backend everything works: I place a product in category A, save category A and when I switch to category B I see that the product is listed here too.

I want to achieve the same thing in a cron class so I used the `CategoryLinkManagementInterface` class to assign my products to category A:

```
*/ Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface */
$this->categoryLinkManagementInterface->assignProductToCategories($productSku, $CategoryIds);
```

This code partially works: if I check category A from backend, I can see my products listed in the category, but if I switch to category B the products aren't there. This happens (I think) because the rule is refreshed on the category save event but I have called no save method in my code.

Because I have tons of categories to process via cron, I'd really like to avoid saving each category one by one (it would increase the time the cron is working) so now I wonder:

1. Is there a way to refresh the category smart rule without saving the category?
2. if I cannot avoid saving the category, is there a quicker way of bulk-saving a bunch of categories all at once instead of going with the `$categoryRepository->save($category)`  method for each category one by one?

Basically, I'd like to do what we already do with the products. With products, we don't save the whole category, we just call the link interface and assign the products that way. I was hoping I could use a rule interface to refresh the rules in the same way but I have not been able to find such code.

Comment: Don't have an answer for your question but just want to make you aware that the smart category rules generate a HUGE amount of database load so I'd really advise that you regenerate the categories as infrequently as you can get away with. I've seen multiple sites crippled by this feature.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I didn't know. Unfortunately I cannot change the behaviour in this particular instance but I'll definitely keep this in mind for future implementations. thanks again